# Can I select a case label in a switch statement and then shows it on the screen in C++?

Tags: c++

everyone! I think it could be a silly question, but I was wondering if it is possible to show a case label in a switch statement in C++. This is the statement:

```
switch(TYPE)
{
  case 'A': 
    (cost <= 30000);
    break;
    
  case 'B':
    (30000 < cost <= 60000);  
    break;
    
  case 'C':
    (cost > 60000);  
    break;  
}
```

In this code, the user writes the cost at the beginning of it. The ranges that are showed in each case are the prices of a product. Let's say they write 62000, so given that it costs more than 60000 it should go to the type C product. So I would like to show the type to the user, and I write:

```
cout <<"TYPE: "<< TYPE <<endl;
```

But when I run the code, this line appears empty. I would like to find the way to put the 'C' there, which is the type that corresponds to the cost. Or at least I would like to know if this is not possible so I can think of another way to make this happen. I appreaciate your time and consideration. :)

Comment: what is this line `(30000 < cost <= 60000);` supposed to do? Also regarding your question, you need to provide a [MRE], `cout <<"TYPE: "<< TYPE <<endl;` should work.

Comment: What is `cost <= 3000`? That is a boolean expresion. It does nothing. What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Please provide [mre]. For instance, where do you put the `cout`, exactly? And how do you set the value of `TYPE`? Since your code doesn't show either of those things.

Comment: You code actually confuses the issue and will trigger people familiar with C++ because it's so wrong.  Can we edit the question to write it more like pseudo-code or make make them comments?  I think you are asking to somehow `switch(cost)` and then have a `case` where `30000 < cost <= 60000`.

Comment: This question badly needs to be edited.  Where you wrote _"This is the statement"_ you should write _This is pseudo-code, because I don't know how to do this in C++_.  Also, please clearly state that your **input** is `cost` and your **output** is `TYPE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your logic might be a bit backwards.  `switch` is used to check against the value of a variable that has already been set.  Additionally, it can only check a single value per `case`; it cannot check a range.

If I interpret your question correctly, I think you want something like this:

```
if (cost <= 30000) {
    TYPE = 'A';
} else if (cost <= 60000) {
    TYPE = 'B';
} else {
    TYPE = 'C';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are going about this backwards.  A `switch` will not accomplish what you want.  You need to use `if..else` instead, eg:

```cpp
cout << "TYPE: ";

if (cost <= 30000)
    cout << 'A': 
else if (cost <= 60000)
    cout << 'B': 
else
    cout << 'C':

cout << endl;
```

Which you can take a step further by wrapping the logic inside a function, eg:

```cpp
char getTYPE(int cost)
{
    if (cost <= 30000)
        return 'A': 
    else if (cost <= 60000)
        return 'B': 
    else
        return 'C':
}

cout << "TYPE: " << getTYPE(cost) << endl;
```